# Python, Multiple plots into one PDF page

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, plot, charts

I have four nice charts that I can save as a PDF file but on 4 pages instead of only 2. I have a  2 charts with financial data of the company and another 2 charts with the prices of stock. I would like to have a one page in PDF with financial date of one company and price of stock. Of course, on the second page I need the same result but for the next company.

Below is my code

```
with PdfPages('multipage_pdf.pdf') as pdf:

    fig1, ax = plt.subplots()
    index = np.arange(n_groups)
    bar_width = 0.35
    opacity = 0.8

    rects1 = plt.bar(index, z, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='b',
                 label='Zysk_(strata)_netto')

    rects2 = plt.bar(index + bar_width, v, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='g',
                 label='Zysk_(strata)_działal_oper')

    rects3 = plt.bar(index + bar_width + bar_width, b, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='y',
                 label='EBITDA')

    plt.xlabel('Kwartaly')
    plt.ylabel('PLN')
    plt.title(companys_to_chart[0])
    plt.xticks(index + bar_width, x)
    plt.legend()
    ax.grid(True)

    plt.tight_layout()
    pdf.savefig()
    plt.close()

    x = company['Date']
    y = company['Close']

    x1 = WIG['Date']
    y1 = WIG['Close']

    fig2, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x,y,label='Price')
    ax.set_ylabel("PLN")
    ax.set_xlabel("Date")


    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    ax2.plot(x1,y1, 'y-', label='WIG')

    myFmt = DateFormatter("%d-%m-%y")
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

    fig2.autofmt_xdate()

    plt.ylabel('Points',size=10)
    plt.title(name_of_company)
    ax.grid(True)

    fig2.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.85, 0.35))

    pdf.savefig()
    plt.close()

##############################################################################
    x_1 = company_2['Kwartal']
    z_1 = company_2['Zysk_(strata)_netto']
    v_1 = company_2['Zysk_(strata)_działal_oper']
    b_1 = company_2['EBITDA']

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    index = np.arange(n_groups)
    bar_width = 0.35
    opacity = 0.8

    rects1 = plt.bar(index, z_1, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='b',
                 label='Zysk_(strata)_netto')

    rects2 = plt.bar(index + bar_width, v_1, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='g',
                 label='Zysk_(strata)_działal_oper')

    rects3 = plt.bar(index + bar_width + bar_width, b_1, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='y',
                 label='EBITDA')

    plt.xlabel('Kwartaly')
    plt.ylabel('PLN')
    plt.title(companys_to_chart[1])
    plt.xticks(index + bar_width, x)
    plt.legend()
    ax.grid(True)

    plt.tight_layout()

    pdf.savefig()
    plt.close()

    x = company['Date']
    y = company['Close']

    x1 = WIG['Date']
    y1 = WIG['Close']

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x,y,label='Price')
    ax.set_ylabel("PLN")
    ax.set_xlabel("Date")


    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    ax2.plot(x1,y1, 'y-', label='WIG')

    myFmt = DateFormatter("%d-%m-%y")
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

    fig.autofmt_xdate()

    plt.ylabel('Points',size=10)
    plt.title(name_of_company_1)
    ax.grid(True)

    fig.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.85, 0.35))

    pdf.savefig()
    plt.close()
```

In the end I have a 4 pages instead of 2 and I am looking for result like below in PDF.
[image]

I hope that my question is clear :) Thanks for all help !

Comment: You need two subplots in each figure. `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)`. Then plot to ax1 and ax2 as desired.

Comment: I am trying to put your line of code into my but not sure where exactly do it (I tried and there was no good output). Could you show it ?Python is  pretty new language for me

Comment: Currently you create two figures `fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()`, `fig, ax2 = plt.subplots()`. Instead, I'm proposing to create a single figure with two axes, `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)`.

Comment: We are going into right direction because I have 2 charts on one page but the second chart is empty. I removed the second figure:
fig2, ax = plt.subplots() 
I also changed:
ax.plot(x,y,label='Price')
    ax.set_ylabel("PLN")
    ax.set_xlabel("Date") into

ax2.plot(x,y,label='Price')
    ax2.set_ylabel("PLN")
    ax2.set_xlabel("Date")

Comment: Also use `ax1.bar` instead of `plt.bar`. Apart one cannot know what's wrong without [mcve].